# Image rotator for the drupal web page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I see few plugins for slidshow/rotator in drupal.

1. http://drupal.org/project/slideshow
2. http://drupal.org/project/views_rotator
3. http://www.bywombats.com/blog/06-08-2010/building-rotating-image-banner-views
4. http://ddblock.myalbums.biz/node/885
5. /http://drupal.org/project/rotor

I am trying to have an image rotator, similar to http://www.oracle.com/index.html

Thanks ins advance.

Comment: What is your specific question? You have not asked anything yet.

Comment: Also, the image rotator on oracle, what do you like about it? (the pager, the effect, ...) Exactly the same will be hard though, except with solid knowledge of javascript, html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience if you really want full control, you need to build the slideshow yourself. At first this may seem difficult, but it's actually fairly "simple" (depending on your background offcourse).

Drupal uses jQuery and by using the [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), you can create pretty much any slideshow.

The jQuery cycle plugin is easy to use:

- add the plugin to your drupal installation (download the .js and add it to your theme)
- in your template make sure your banner/slideshow-items are all in 1 div or container
- write your own js-file with following code (where container stands for ID of the container div):

> ```
> $('#container')
> .before('<div id="nav">') 
> .cycle({
>     fx:    'fade', 
>     speed:  2500, 
>     pager: #nav
>  });
> ```

This will create a slideshow on the container div and will create a navigation div before the slideshow with the page-elements. (you will get all kinds of selectors such as .active to get full control over the navigation)

---

Using a module is ok, but you will need to make changes specific to what you want and sometimes this could take longer then just making it yourself.

If you still would want to use a module, I'd say rotor banner (last update date 25th of may) or slideshow (last update date 5th of april). However I believe slideshow will be too light for what you want to achieve, and rotor banner a bit too heavy...

Comment: thanks you so much for ur answer.. i came to the same conclusion, and I could make it to work.. But, I saw an issue with the plugin on IE8. I opened another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289422/jquery-cycle-plugin-and-ie-8 .. please give your comments.. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are another cool and crossbrowsing module: http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

Main benefit of it is very good customization by css and tpl files. Also it has a good and easy video-guide (link on the module page).

Also this module has some dependenies modules those may be very useful. Check it!

Comment: thanks.. I currently using this plugin after reading a bit about all of it.. thanks for ur help.